# How to populate DTO class string fields using JPA CriteriaQuery on Entity having enum fields?

Tags: java, jpa, enums, dao, criteria-api

I'm using JPA Criteria API, and in my query multiselect I want to retrieve an enum attribute, and not the enum itself.

This is my query :

```
final CriteriaQuery<MyClassDTO> query = builder.createQuery(MyClassDTO.class);
```

in `MyClassDTO` I have 4 fields as following:

```
private String icon;
private String provenance;
private int sizeX;
private int sizeY;
```

And the path I'm retrieving data from is :

```
final Root<MyClass> from = query.from(MyClass.class);
```

`MyClass` has 3 fields :

```
@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EnumTileIcon enumTileIcon;

@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EnumProvenance enumProvenance;

@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EnumSize enumSize;
```

What I want to do is to populate the `MyClassDTO` using the `query.multiselect`, something like this :

```
query.multiselect(
    from.get(MyClass_.enumTileIcon.toString()),
    from.get(MyClass_.enumProvenance.name()),
    from.get(MyClass_.enumSize.getWidth()),
    from.get(MyClass_.enumSize.getHeight())
);
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I think you wil have to use tuple query for this.

Comment: @Antoniossss how can I do that ?

Comment: builder.createQuery(Tuple.class);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure about the role of multiselect. But when dealing with **projections** what this seems to be you can use `CriteriaBuilder.construct()`

Create constructor to `MyClassDTO` like (add params if needed)

```
public MyClassDTO(EnumTileIcon icon, EnumProvenance provenance) {
    this.icon=icon.toString();
    this.provenance=provenance.toString();
}
```

Call the constructor in query like (add get params to match constructor params if needed)

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClassDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(MyClassDTO.class);
Root<MyClass> root = cq.from(MyClass.class);
cq.select(cb.construct(MyClassDTO.class,
             root.get("enumTileIcon"), root.get("enumProvenance")));
```

Then you will be able to get

```
TypedQuery<MyClassDTO> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
```