# Spring Data JPA - How to convert Query result to entity class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

Am using Spring Data JPA with spring boot application. I have an entity class with few properties. Consider I have 10 properties associated with the entity `User` and I want to retrieve only few of them (username,password,firstname,lastname,email).

So I have wrote a query to get the 5 fields only, but the method does not return entity object, instead it returns a plain object.

How can I cast the query result to entity in Spring Data JPA ?

```
@Query("select userName,password,firstName,lastName,email from User")
public List<User> getUsers();
```

Comment: Look in any reference for "JPQL". This is nothing to do with "Spring"

Comment: @DN1 Answer might not have but maybe just because the annotation `@Query`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a result class and then change the query a bit:

```
package com.example;

public class ResultClass{

    String userName,password,firstName,lastName,email;

    public ResultClass(String userName, String password
          , String firstName, String lastName, String email){
         // set fields;
    }
}
```

and query:

```
@Query("select new com.example.ResultClass(userName,password
              ,firstName,lastName,email) from User")
public List<ResultClass> getUsers();
```

The order of selection must match the constructor ordering.

Comment: This is the correct way in `JPQL`. @ansar-samad If interested to change that to `CriteriaQuery` check the corresponding way to do the projection here [How to populate DTO class string fields using `JPA` `CriteriaQuery` on `Entity` having enum fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409619/how-to-populate-dto-class-string-fields-using-jpa-criteriaquery-on-entity-having)

Answer (score 0):

If your Target class is not entity class and you need to parse, Please refer below answer..

[ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420697/spring-data-jpa-how-can-query-return-non-entities-objects-or-list-of-objects/60144642#60144642)