# OneToOne hibernate get only the result of the join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to get only the result of a OneToOne join ?

For example :

Address (id , country, street, ...)
Country (id, label)

i want to create a DAO which get directly the label of the country :

```
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // Some annotation to join with country and get the label 
    private countryLabel;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write such a method in a DAO. You need to write and execute a query. That's described in the documentation. Read it, and try something. What your code shows, however, is not a DAO. It's an entity. What's the problem with `public String getCountryLabel() { return this.country.getLabel(); }`?

Comment: Look for _projection_ & `DTO`. For example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47471384/6413377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47409619/6413377). Post then your effort as code and tell what fails if fails.